# How to show post of a specific category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to show only post from a particular category id

I have a category section and i have my relationship between categories and post working i just want to show post a specific category id instead of calling all post.

I have tried this but it's not working.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h5><td><%=link_to post.category(1).title, post %></td></h5>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Let's get this straight: You have a collection of `@posts`, and each post can be in many `categories`. So what are you trying to display? A filtered list of those `@posts`; only the ones which are in category `1`? Or, for each post, the title of their "first" `category`? Or, the "first" post - if any - which is in category `1`?

Comment: What is "Not Working?" An error? Unexpected behavior? Please describe what you want to happen, then describe what is actually happening.

Comment: i want the post in category id 1 to show at that section instead of all posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to show a post of a category id, this should help

```
<% Post.where(category_id: 1).each do |post| %>
```

where that 1 would be the category id

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h5><td><%=link_to post.category(1).title, post %></td></h5>
<% end %>
```

...this part looks suspicious: `category(1)`. If post belongs_to category, try this:

```
post.category.title
```

If a post has_many (or has_and_belongs_to_many) categories, try this:

```
post.categories.first.title
```

One of those two should give you what you want.

Beyond that, I'm not sure you're trying to link. You're linking to a post, but the linktext is the category title. So, if you have three posts in the category, "Recipes," all three links will say "Recipes." Are you trying to link to the post or the category? Either way, the linktext should relate to the url.